Quadrilateral constructed by Four Circles is a Tangential quadrilateral
Consider following constellation of four circles tangent to each other:

Question: How to show that the triangle $O_1O_2O_3O_4$ is a tangential quadrilateral using only "primitive angle chasing" techniques?
I want to emphasise that I'm interested in such "elementary proof" which not uses inversion transformations as tool.
Note, that we can observe immediately the relation $\angle BAD = \dfrac{1}{2}(\angle DO_1A + \angle AO_2B)$ and as consequence, we can easily deduce that the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is concyclic, ie. its vertices lie on a circle. In similar spirit - so via just elementary angle chasing - I hoped that it's also possible to derive that $O_1O_2O_3O_4$ is a tangential quadrilateral.
Observe, that a priori it's not clear that the circle $ABCD$ going trought $A,B,C$ and $D$ intersects $O_1O_2O_3O_4$ in $A,B,C$ and $D$ tangentially, that's the crux.

Do you know the classification of a tangential quadrilateral?

@CalvinLin: You meant that it should satisfy equality $O_1O_2+ O_3O_4= O_2O_3+ O_4O_1$?

Right, so we are done.

@CalvinLin: with this, that clearly lies on the nose, thanks!

In fact it's not true, in general, that circle $$ is tangent to $_1_2_3_4$, see this figure.

A quadrilateral is a tangential quadrilateral if and only if the opposite sides add up to the same total length.
It is obvious that the given quadrilateral satisfies this condition, hence we are done.

The incircle of quadrilateral $O_1O_2O_3O_4$ does not have to be tangent to the sides at $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.

@timon92 Ah thanks. I erroneously thought those lengths were uniquely determined, but clearly they are not.
